# TP-Link router disconnects from internet when main PC goes to sleep

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

My TP-Link router (AC1750) disconnects from the internet when my main PC goes to sleep. Rebooting router or shutting off/turning on PC often restores the internet on my network. Can someone recommend a fix?

Edit: I have a separate issue of the main PC going to sleep on its own at seemingly random intervals.

Comment: That is highly abnormal behavior. Do you have an application on the computer that is intimately tied with the router?  Disconnect the computer from the router (not sleep). What happens to the router. 

I would do two things here:  (1) do a hard reset of the router to factory specs, and then (2) upgrade the firmware on the router and set it up again

Comment: What are connection options for Internet Connectivity? Some routers have options like Always-On, On-Demand or simply Manual. Just make sure that Always-On is set rather than On-Demand or equivalent if present, just in case.

Comment: No applications tied to router that I am aware of. Disconnecting computer from router does not appear to affect connection. Firmware is already at latest available. I am hesitant to do a hard router reset at this point but open to it if all other solutions exhausted (would lose stored wifi MAC addresses, MAC to local IP mappings, etc). My connection is Dynamic IP, so no option for Always-On, On-Demand, etc.

Comment: Something is wrong here. I would reset the router to correct this.

Comment: Is the router's firmware [up to date](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-c7/#Firmware)?

Comment: Yes, the router's firmware is the latest available as per manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to resolve the issue. When I would unplug the ethernet cable to my sleeping PC from the router, I could access the router interface and internet with my other connected devices. As soon as I plugged it back in, I could not.

In the end, I determined I had an IP conflict on my network. I was assigning static IP and DNS addresses on the PC ethernet card that must have conflicted when PC is put to sleep. Removing the static settings from ethernet card seem to resolve issue for now.

Thank you John for original troubleshooting tip.